# Parameter binding with Hibernate SessionFactory statistics

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql

Here's an excerpt:

```
    this.sessionFactory.getStatistics().setStatisticsEnabled(true);
```

..

```
    final Map<String, Object> customParams =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
    customParams.put("active", true);
    genericDao.getModifiedDate("getModifiedDateForAllActiveTestObjects", customParams);
    String[] queries = this.sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueries();
```

This gives me the query as:

```
SELECT max(test.modifiedDate) FROM GenericDomain AS test where test.active= :active
```

This code is actually in my unit/integration tests and I want to know if the parameter-binding actually happened i.e. the where clause in the final SQL query against the DB infact contains test.active=true.

Is this even possible? If not, then how else can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its the best way but i used it in one of my Projects (C#). I implemented a custom log4net appender which catches the sql NH sending to the db.

Configuration

```
var sqlLogger = (Logger)LogManager.GetRepository().GetLogger("NHibernate.SQL");
m_sqlappender = new NhSqlAppender(10);  // size of the ring-buffer
sqlLogger.AddAppender(m_sqlappender);
if (!sqlLogger.IsEnabledFor(Level.Debug))
    sqlLogger.Level = Level.Debug;
```

Usage

```
string[] queries = m_sqlappender.CurrentQueries.Pop();
```

CurrentQueries is implemented as a ringbuffer-stack so i can get the latest queries

Comment: that is interesting. However, keep in mind that these are unit/integration tests I'm talking about. The next step for me is to look for the presence of a certain clause in the queries. The queries you've caught are SQL queries generated by ORM which tend to be complicated and clumsy to work with.